# Gmail not sending 'In-Reply-To' header

Tags: smtp, gmail

According to [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) an `In-Reply-To` header should be sent if there was a `Message-Id` header in the message to which you are responding.

> The "In-Reply-To:" field will contain the contents of the "Message- 
>   ID:" field of the message to which this one is a reply (the "parent
>   message").  If there is more than one parent message, then the "In-
>   Reply-To:" field will contain the contents of all of the parents'
>   "Message-ID:" fields.  If there is no "Message-ID:" field in any of
>   the parent messages, then the new message will have no "In-Reply-To:" 
>   field.

However I'm not seeing this header is always being sent. I am using Mandrill's inbound email and the header just doesn't exist.

Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that certain special characters can break Gmail. In my case it was in the subject line, but it could well be the same with other headers (unconfirmed).

So replying to an email with this subject line did not set `In-Reply-To`:

```
Simon's Store® Shipping Confirmation #9038060
```

This did work:

```
Simon's Store Shipping Confirmation #9038060
```

I'm guessing this is a bug in GMail as the `Message-Id` header *is* correctly send (I see  it in the message 'source').

So stick to [simple ASCII](http://developer.telemessage.com/faq/how-do-i-encode-non-ascii-characters-in-an-email-subject-line) if you want `In-Reply-To` to get sent.

---

Regarding forwarding:

For testing I just added a forwarding rule to forward 'real' customer service emails to my Mandrill account. Initially I assumed this was the reason the `In-Reply-To` header wasn't being sent, but I noticed it was being sent for some but not all messages. So if you're just testing you can use this forwarding feature and expect to see a valid `In-Reply-To` header.

Comment: Note: if you send a `®` symbol interactively on gmail.com it will convert it to (R) for the subject line and this problem doesn't occur. I am talking about an email sent programatically (mandrill / Amazon SES etc)

Comment: i dont see a in-Reply-To and References header in auto-reply messages sent by Gmail. What could possibly be missing.No Special Characters as well

Comment: @zee I didn't consider auto-replies yet. I'm not sure what the expected behavior should be but I agree it would be nice if they did it.

Comment: if in-reply-to and references fields are missing in auto-replies, how can we figure out the original message of this auto-reply. I normally compare the in-reply-to value to figure out the relation. Any Suggestions . i have asked this q here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635709/3148412